# Dnspython can't resolve anything

Tags: python, ubuntu, dns

My sample code is

```
import dnspython as dns
import dns.resolver

result = dns.resolver.query('google.com', 'A')
for ipval in result:
    print('IP', ipval.to_text())
```

Which gives me the error
`dns.resolver.NoResolverConfiguration: Resolver configuration could not be read or specified no nameservers.`

/etc/resolv.conf contains "1.1.1.1" and nothing else and netplan nameservers are also set to 1.1.1.1.

Machine is running python 3.8.5 on ubuntu 20.04.

Why is it giving me that error and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out!

Huge facepalm. I forgot to put nameserver 1.1.1.1 instead of just 1.1.1.1 on /etc/resolv.conf

So, indeed, the configuration was wrong.